# Kicad: How to add a Filled Zone around a Net with a single pin?

Tags: pcb, kicad

I am designing a PCB in Kicad and I need to add a filled zone around a single pin (pin needs to become part of the zone, not an island).

For some reason, when the "Copper Zone" tool provides me with a list of nets, it does not seem to include the nets which only have one node.

The reason I only have one node in that net is b/c I am connecting an incoming
+110V line to a switch contact. I've tried connecting the switch to a Power
Symbol, to a PWR_FLAG and to a hierarchical pin, but the generated net still
only contains one node:

```
(net (code 11) (name /Mains_Power/+110V)
  (node (ref SW1) (pin 1)))
```

What can I do to make the "Copper Zone" tool allow me to select that net? Is there some other way to create some copper around that pin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you show the pin going to something like a test point in the circuit? If it doesn't connect to anything it won't be seen as a net and having it connected to an otherwise unused power pin will not generate a net either.

There's a design that I did recently that had a wire coming onto the board and being soldered to a piece of copper - on the circuit, i made the copper = a test point and the footprint/decal in the PCB section I defined a shape of copper which had a pin number

Comment: Thanks Andy! This gave me the right idea, although I did it slightly differently. I connected my switch to a CONN_1 connector as you suggested, but I did not give it any footprint. The connection itself made the net appear in the Zone Fill tool, so I just drew the shape of the copper I wanted around the switch contact.